# iTunes Connect doesn't ask for updated screenshots?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I've updated my iPhone app to support the iPhone 5 screen..

I've done this before for another app and I was forced to upload new screenshots taken with the iPhone 5.

This time however, iTunes Connect just displays the status as "waiting for review" and isn't mentioning anything about the screenshots..

I'm slightly worried something has gone wrong? App works great on iPhone 5 and simulator though.

Comment: I don't think it forced me to upload new iPhone 5 screenshots when I updated my app to support the new screen size - after the update went live, though, it worked fine on iPhone 5. Have you tried editing the metadata and uploading the new screenshots manually?

Comment: Even if its not asking you to add iPhone5 screenshots, but it is highly recommended to add this screenshots, as Apple displays iPhone5 screenshots on iTunes. Also, it may happen that they just block your application review process just because you have not added screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app got accepted yesterday, no word about the screenshots.

App works fine on iPhone 5, mailed Apple to complain this probably is a bug (iTUnes Connect does not recognize localized Default.png, which is what is checked to verify it is iPhone 5 optimized I believe.)

Comment: Try to name your iPhone 5 Screenshot with this name Default-568h@2x.png :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out Apple can block apps during the review process that have something wrong with metadata. If they decide your metadata is wrong they'll just change your app's status to "Metadata Rejected".

Here's the quote from the rules for this status:

> Appears when specific metadata items aside from your binary have not
>   passed review. To resolve the issue, edit the metadata in iTunes
>   Connect and your existing binary is then reused for the review
>   process. You receive a communication from App Review in the Resolution
>   Center regarding the reason for the metadata rejection.

Answer (score 1):

When things change to the AppStore (Apple adds a device) they might require you to get new screenshots. But if nothing changed in their system, it's normal that they don't ask.

Don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

They copy over the screenshots from your last version of the app (or is your Retina4 screenshot section in itunesconnect empty?). So if you don´t want to update them, it should be okay like this.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your app has not hit review (and now as of the 21st) and won't be reviewed until after the 29th. Once your app hits review, it will become rejected for the missing screenshots. If you want to save yourself some time and pain, update the screenshots while Apple is on their downtime for the Christmas holiday. You'll thank yourself later.